# Any way to pop up two stack frames in python? (Return from outer calling function)

Tags: python, function, stack, metaprogramming

Scenario:

```
def inner(a, b):
    if a > b:
        returnOuter() #this should pop back into main


def outer():
    inner(3,1)
    print 'this should not be printed!'

def main()
    outer()
    print 'this should be the only message printed'
```

Is this possible?  Can it be done by manipulating the stack manually?  The only requirement is that the functionality is entirely contained within the inner function (no exception catching outside, etc).

Comment: My thought: _why_ do you want to do this? There are better ways to implement this kind of control flow, and I can't imagine what reason you would have not to use them.

Comment: raise an exception in `inner` and catch it in `main`.

Comment: @Kevin er, two requirements :)

the other one is that I don't want anything outside to have to accommodate it.

Comment: @DavidZ i'm basically implementing an emulator, and the behavior of some of the opcodes necessitates this.

Comment: @odken - if you think your design neccesitates this - then i am fairly confident that your design is wrong.